# How to deserialiaze json object with nested json array

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

I'm new to Java and i'm trying to deserialize a Json object with nested Json array of object with gson library but facing some difficulty.

Will need some help on how to do that in a correct way with gson library?

POJOs:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "Error")
public class ErrorData {

    private String Source;
    private String ReasonCode;
    private String ErrorCode;
    private String Description;
// getters and setters
}

@JsonRootName(value = "Errors")
public class ErrorsDataRes {
    @SerializedName("Error")
    private List<ErrorData> Error;
// getters and setters
}
```

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String data =
 "{\"Errors\":{\"Error\":[{\"Source\":\"INPUT\",\"ReasonCode\":\"INVALID_FIELD_VALUE\",\"ErrorCode\":\"E0001\",\"Description\":\"Invalid Field Value\"}]}}";
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        ErrorsDataRes errors = gson.fromJson(data, ErrorsData.class);
}
```

I'm expecting to deserialize Json string into my ErrorsDataRes object but the result is an empty object. Any ideas ?

Comment: The output has only the ErrorsDataRes.class. Input has 2 levels of nesting. What you are looking for is 1 level of nesting- starting directly from {\"Error\":[{\"Source\":\"INPUT\"...

Comment: Please up-vote if it helped !

Answer (score 1):

POJO class is incorrect . Please try this.

POJO :

```
 public class ErrorData {
    @SerializedName("Source")
    private String Source;
    @SerializedName("ReasonCode")
    private String ReasonCode;
    @SerializedName("ErrorCode")
    private String ErrorCode;
    @SerializedName("Description")
    private String Description;
}
public class ErrorsData {
    @SerializedName("Error")
    private List<ErrorData> Error;
   //getters and setters
}

public class ErrorsDataRes {

    @SerializedName("Errors")
    private ErrorsData errors;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data =
                "{\"Errors\":{\"Error\":[{\"Source\":\" INPUT\",\"ReasonCode\":\"INVALID_FIELD_VALUE\",\"ErrorCode\":\"E0001\",\"Description\":\"Invalid Field Value\"}]}}";
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        ErrorsDataRes errors = gson.fromJson(data, ErrorsDataRes.class);
        System.out.println(errors);
    }
```

Comment: Thank You, i was not considering 2-level nested structure.